# Flex VideoDisplay: setting the thumbnail on a video which hasn't been played yet?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, thumbnails, videodisplay, flex-mx

I have an `mx:VideoDisplay` object in Flex, and I wanted to change the initial image which is displayed for the VideoDisplay for the source video. The reason being, the frame that is initially being shown simply looks too funny to be taken seriously? An alternative is to layer an image on top of the videodisplay and then just remove it from the stage once I have set the video to play, but I would like to avoid having to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use states and show the image before playing the video and use timer to remove it after n seconds and play video. 
I am not sure it its the correct way, but I implemented the same way, when I got the same requirement.
Let m

Comment: this is the way I ended up doing it, just a pain to have to do that to be honest. Not really a sustainable method when you are working with a large quantity of video files